# NHibernate - MYSQL - remote db server connection string issue

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I have a C#.Net windows application.

Where MYSQL is installed on server say 11.90.109.19

And C#.Net windows application is running on another conmputer.

I am using Spring.Net and NHibernate

Nhibernate connection string configured using Spring.Net file as

```
<db:provider id="DbProvider" provider="SqlServer-2.0"
    connectionString="Server=tcp:(local),3306;Database=vault14092012;Trusted_Connection=False;User ID=root;Password=root"/>
```

But is is giving following error

[image]

Urgent  help required.
Below connection string is working fine

```
<db:provider id="DbProvider"
                   provider="SqlServer-2.0"
                   connectionString="server=localhost;Database=vault14092012;User ID=root;Password=root"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an NHibernate exception. Seems like you have unsupported keywords in your connection string. You should paste the entire error message instead of screenshot.

Judging by the first few visible letters (tr), I would say that the problem is in `Trusted_Connection=false` part. Looks like MySQL doesn't support it.

Here you can find more info about MySQL connection strings: http://connectionstrings.com/mysql

Have you tried with something like this:

```
<db:provider 
    id="DbProvider"
    provider="SqlServer-2.0"
    connectionString="server=11.90.109.19;Port=3306;Database=vault14092012;User ID=root;Password=root"/>
```